# How to show the value in one column for a specified value in another column in the same row

Tags: function, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

The title says it all. I need a function that gives me the value in column A if the value of column G in the same row has the string `NEGADO` in it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula in Google sheets OR Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this formula to return all rows**

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G<>"NEGATO",,A2:A))
```

[image]

**OR** the following *(based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635344/function-to-show-the-value-of-column-a-in-a-row-if-a-specified-value-in-column-g/66637655#comment117797128_66635532))* **to return just the rows that meet the condition**

```
=filter(A2:A,G2:G="NEGATO")
```

[image]

*(do change ranges according to your needs and locale)*

Comment: I had read the question as needing the number value from column A. =sumIf would be the best option then

Answer (score 1):

=IFERROR(IF(FIND("NEGADO",G1),A1,""),"")

Comment: I need that but for a list of rows, sorry if i wasnt so clear.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but you can copy that function to other cells.

Comment: Basicly, I have a table and a want to filter only the rows that have the string in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
This should work on whole column (for google sheets)

```
=filter(A1:A,G1:G="NEGADO")
```